# insert into database many to many relationship .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to make a many to many relationship. I have made the following Classes for the tables.

```
public class Class {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string ClassName { get; set; }
  public string ClassRequirements { get; set; }
  public int HitDie { get; set; }
  public IList<ClassRace> ClassRaces { get; set; } 
}
public class Race {
  public int RaceID { get; set; }
  public string RaceName { get; set; }
  public string RaceFeatures { get; set; }
  public List<ClassRace> ClassRaces { get; set; }
}
public class ClassRace {
  public int ClassID { get; set; }
  public Class Class { get; set; }
  public int RaceID { get; set; }
  public Race Race { get; set; }
}
```

I initialize values in the tables when the program is ran for the first time.

```
var cl1 = new Class() {
  ClassName = "Barbarian",
  ClassRequirements = "13 Strength",
  HitDie = 12,
  ClassRaces = new List<ClassRace>() 
};
Race rc1 = new Race() {
  RaceName = "Elf",
  RaceFeatures = "DarkVision. +2 Wisdom",
  ClassRaces = new List<ClassRace>()
};
var cr = new ClassRace {
  Class = cl1,
  Race = rc1
};
rc0.ClassRaces.Add(cr);
cl1.ClassRaces.Add(cr);
```

On my `DbContext` I have this line of code which I believed will fill in my `ClassID` and `RaceId` automatically in the table however when I run the program this table will be empty and both rows are `NULL`.

```
public DbSet<Race> Races { get; set; }
public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
public DbSet<ClassRace> ClassRaces { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  modelBuilder.Entity<ClassRace>().
    HasKey(cr => new { cr.ClassID, cr.RaceID });
  modelBuilder.Entity<ClassRace>().
    HasOne(x => x.Race).
    WithMany(x => x.ClassRaces).
    HasForeignKey(x => x.RaceID).
    OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict).
    IsRequired();
  modelBuilder.Entity<ClassRace>().
    HasOne(x => x.Class).
    WithMany(x => x.ClassRaces).
    HasForeignKey(x => x.ClassID).
    OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict).
    IsRequired();
}
```

Why is my `ClassRaces` table `NULL`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you populate your table with data ? Can you show where this happens ?

Comment: Inside my DBInit class I initialize. I give Class cl1 values and Race rc1 values and edited to add where I link Class and Race in ClassRace table

Comment: *which I believed will fill in my ClassID and RaceId automatically* -- No, they only define the relationships. You need a `SaveChanges` call in the initialization code (where `rc0` is a typo). Or use [data seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).

Comment: Ah yes there is that typo which does indeed add 1 row now to my table. I will also take a look at data seeding thank you.

Comment: @GertArnold Is there a better way to assign for example. The Race Elf to 10 classes instead of having to do this line of code 10 times with a different cl1, cl2, cl3, ... every time?

Comment: Nope. Seeding by this method lacks any sophistication. Positively stated, it follows the KISS principle.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you just set the Id values as you are operating insert (especially focus on what you did in RaceClass model):

Will give you an example of data seeding in OnModelCreating method (You can also perform loops as i saw one of your comments):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().HasData(new Class
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    ClassName = "Barbarian",
                    ClassRequirements = "13 Strength",
                    HitDie = 12
                });



modelBuilder.Entity<Race>().HasData(new Race
                {
                     Id = 1,
                     RaceName = "Elf",
                     RaceFeatures = "DarkVision. +2 Wisdom"
                });

modelBuilder.Entity<ClassRace >().HasData(new ClassRace 
                {
                     Id = 1,
                     RaceId = 1,
                     ClassId= 1
                });
```

Call _context.SaveChanges() at bottom of you method.

Comment: This does not work as I get the following error 

`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ClassRaces_Classes_ClassID". The conflict occurred in database "DndDB", table "dbo.Classes", column 'Id'.`

trying to add the ID's through modelbuilder Hadata.

Comment: Check for any typo and be sure class and race are created before classrace